# Access Tridion object in Browser Console?

Tags: cme, experience-manager, gui-extensions, javascript

I was trying the answers to this question: [How to mass delete Tridion MessageCenter warnings?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7375/46)

I noticed in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, in the Browser console it seems the slide out menu is available using `SDL`, but I can't seem to access the `Tridion` object directly.

**How should we access the Tridion object when debugging from the console?**

*I understand this isn't Anguilla, per se, but an extension across SDL products.*

In the GUI Extension (Anguilla) documentation, I see a references to `SDL` in `contents.html`:

- `SDL`

  - `SDL.Client`

    - `Client.Application`

But I'm not sure how/if this relates to the `Tridion` object.

**Edit**: I've followed John Winter's example from this question: [How to Add SDL Media Manager to the Slide-out Navigation?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7333/46). *So adding new items and extending the slide out navigation is actually clear (I removed that part from this question).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No takers, so I'm posting what my colleagues explained, as a community post (no points, but feel free to update and add details).

With SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, you will find the Browser console different because of extra frames from the *slide out navigation* (thanks [PeterK](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/141/peter-kjaer)). So these won't work directly:

- $messages
- Tridion.*

[UIBeardCore](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/206/ui-beardcore) pointed out the solution is something like:

`window.top.frames[0].Tridion.getApplicationWindow().Tridion.MessageCenter.getMessages().forEach(function(message){message.doArchive();})`

This worked to clear messages on an SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 setup.

Comment: +1 for sharing all the same Alvin thanks. The question begs then - is there an extension point to be added or would be be expected to use this DOM 'workaround' and change when the page DOM updates in Hotfixes/Service Packs/Upgrades etc.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, though this would only affect poking around the browser. The slide out is extendable with .ascx files or some XML configuration to add links to iframed pages (quite cool) and within Tridion, clients (CME or XPM), extensions just work.