# $display is not defined | Anguilla

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, 2013-sp1-hr1

On "Dashborad" or "WorkflowActivities" view, when I run `$display.getView()` in the console of the browser, I get the desired result as below:

[image]

But if I leave the page idle for sometime, the same code start throwing the exception as below:

[image]

Any idea why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I had issues selecting things in the console because of the slide out navigation pane. Here's an explation from PeterK about extra frames and a work-around from @UIBeardCore: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7418/46 (`window.top.frames[0].Tridion.getApplicationWindow()`).

Answer (score 4):

If it worked before and it doesn't after you

> leave the page idle for some time

Then either:

- something is killing the $display parameter (in which case I'm sure you'd see a plethora of errors):

  - perhaps you've some script that executes in between it working and not working (is there a consistent timeframe for example) and causes a refocus on another frame without access to your require params/$display.view
- or something within the context of the debug console has changed

Can you confirm if, after the error presents itself, you are viewing the same frameset as identified below (note that there may be more than 1 dashboard displayed and not all will necessary behave the same with regards available parameters etc.)

[image]

*I presume* that this is a problem that's causing some script you're writing to fall over (as opposed to purely being angry that the console debug fails you - *I've been there, believe me!*) - is it possible to simply test that you have access to the correct params in your code and gracefully fall over?

Or perhaps you could attach an event to the item you're losing focus from and use breakpoints or similar to track where it's going which may lead to why (especially if the console gives you access to the call stack etc.)